# Reading filecontent pairs of chars into array

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

In C++, how can I read the contents of a file into an array of strings? I need this for a file that consists of pairs of chars separated by spaces as follows:

```
cc cc cc cc cc cc
cc cc cc cc cc cc
cc cc cc cc cc cc
cc cc cc cc cc cc
```

c can be any char, *including* space! Attempt:

```
ifstream myfile("myfile.txt");
int numPairs = 24;
string myarray[numPairs];

for( int i = 0; i < numPairs; i++) {
    char read;
    string store = "";

    myfile >> read;
    store += read;

    myfile >> read;
    store += read;

    myfile >> read;

    myarray[i] = store;
}
```

The problem is that this just skips spaces alltogether, hence leading to wrong values. What do I need to change to make it recognize spaces?

Answer (score 2):

That's expected behavior, since `operator>>`, by defaults, skips whitespace.

The solution is to use the `get` method, which is a low level operation that reads raw bytes from the stream without any formatting.

```
char read;
if(myfile.get(read)) // add some safety while we're at it
    store += read;
```

By the way, VLAs (arrays with a non constant size) are non standard in C++. You should either specify a constant size, or use a container such as `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

If the input is exact like you say the following code will work:

```
ifstream myfile("myfile.txt");
int numPairs = 24;
string myarray[numPairs];

EDIT: if the input is from STDIN
for( int i = 0; i < numPairs; i++) {
    myarray[i] = "";
    myarray[i] += getchar();
    myarray[i]+= getchar();
    getchar(); // the space or end of line

}

EDIT: If we don't now the number of pairs beforehand
      we shoud use a resizable data structure, e.g. vector<string>
vector<string> list;
// read from file stream
while (!myfile.eof()) {
    string temp = "";
    temp += myfile.get();
    temp += myfile.get();
    list.push_back(temp);
    myfile.get();
}
```

Comment: Great. Now what if I don't know the number of pairs beforehand?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, one final question: The way you are using the vector, it gets resized all the time, doesn't it? The file I will be using in the end contains a bit more than the 24 pairs I used for the example , so is there a way to automatically determine the size needed before reading the pairs? (Also, what I need in my program is the number of "columns" and "rows" in the file - I guess I can use a counter for the cols related to myfile.get() and use if to check for \n manually for the rowcounter - but that is while reading the pairs, what about beforehand?)

Comment: Never loop on `eof`. Just test the stream itself: `while(myfile)`.

Comment: @Ben I don't know how to do that without reading the file. You can either indicate the number of pairs or rows and cols at the beginning of the file or use the method you describe to know the rows and cols but don't store the pairs, when you finish, close the file and reopen the file but now you have the number of rows and cols. It's all I can think ;)

Comment: Well, when I'm using the vector as you suggested, I can do both reading and increasing row/colcounter in one step since I don't need to wory about the size. Still I would like to be able to initialise the size of the vector to some sensible startvalue. How can that be done? Could I mazbe change the actual filesize of the textfile itself somehow and then based on that allocate memory for my vector before I start all the reading?

Comment: Ohhh, great idea! It could work, but only if the pairs are stored in one line because the new lines '\n' are characters and count int the file size counter and then how to know the number of characters that are new lines???

Comment: Not quite sure I understand wht you are saying. I was thinking: 1.) Obtain the size of the actual txt-file. 2.) Allocate memory for the vector in the amount of the filesize. Does it work like this at all?

Comment: I think you are complicating your life. Is not? :)